# How to match names separated by "and" excluding "and" itself using regex?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to solve http://play.inginf.units.it/#/level/10

I have some strings as follows:

title={AUTOMATIC ROCKING DEVICE},
author={**Diaz, Navarro David** and **Gines, Rodriguez Noe**},
year={2006},

title={The sitting position in neurosurgery: a retrospective analysis of 488 cases},
author={**Standefer, Michael** and **Bay, Janet W** and **Trusso, Russell**},
journal={Neurosurgery},

title={Fuel cells and their applications},
author={**Kordesch, Karl** and **Simader, G{"u}nter** and **Wiley, John**},
volume={117},

I need to match the names in bold. I tried the following regex:

```
(?<=author={).+(?=})
```

But it matches the entire string inside `{}`. I understand why is it so but how can I break the pattern with `and`?

Comment: Try `(?<=\bauthor={[^{}]*)(?=[^{}]*})\b\w+,(?:\s*(?!and\b)\w+)+` https://regex101.com/r/i7YoVT/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a little while to get the samples to show up in your link. What about:

```
(?:^\s*author={|\G(?!^) and )\K(?:(?! and |},).)+
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6KUYAJ/1)

---

- `(?:^\s*author={|\G(?!^) and )` - Either match start of a line followed by 0+ whitespace chars and literally match 'author={` **or** assert position at end of previous match but negate start-line;
- `\K` - Reset starting point of reported match;
- `(?:(?! and |},).)+` - Match any if it's not followed by ' and ' **or** match a '}' followed by a comma.

Above will also match 'others' as per last sample in linked test. If you wish to exclude 'others' then maybe add the option to the negated list as per:

```
(?:^\s*author={|\G(?!^) and )\K(?:(?! and |},|\bothers\b).)+
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Luukx4/10)

---

In the comment section we established above would not work for given linked website. Apparently its JS based which would support zero-width lookbehind. Therefor try:

```
(?<=\bauthor={(?:(?!\},).*?))\b[A-Z]\S*\b(?:,? [A-Z]\S*\b)*
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bAOugn/1)

- `(?<=` - Open lookbehind;

  - `\bauthor={` - Match word-boundary and literally 'author={';
  - `(?:(?!\},).*?))` - Open non-capture group to match a negative lookahead for '},' and 0+ (lazy) characters. Close lookbehind;
- `\b[A-Z]\S*\b` - Match anything between two word-boundaries starting with a capital letter A-Z followed by 0+ non-whitespace chars;
- `(?:,? [A-Z]\S*\b)*` - A 2nd non-capture group to keep matching comma/space seperated parts of a name.

Comment: To get the examples I went here `http://play.inginf.units.it/#/` then filled in the form, start the test and changed the url to `http://play.inginf.units.it/#/level/10`

Comment: Exactly what I had to do too =)

Comment: @JvdV Don't know why but this regex is not working in the original site. Probably because it doesn't accept `\G` and `\K`, not sure.

Comment: @ArpitShukla, yes who knows. If it's JS based you may use a zero-width lookbehind, like `(?<=\bauthor={(?:(?!\},).*?))(.+?)(?: and |},|\bothers\b)+` and it would capture the names in a capture group. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/eM3vfT/1) demo.

Comment: This new regex also matches the `and`s.

Comment: @ArpitShukla, it's why I used capture groups. Did you open the linked demo? If you don't want to use a capture group, then maybe `(?<=\bauthor={(?:(?!\},).*?))\b[A-Z]\S*\b(?:,? [A-Z]\S*\b)*`. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/bAOugn/1) demo.

Comment: This works perfectly, can you please update the answer with this regex and some explanation on how this works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If using a lookbehind assertion is supported and matching word characters, you might use:

```
(?<=\bauthor={[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*)[A-Z][^\s,]*,(?:\s+[A-Z][^\s,]*)+\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Postive lookahead, assert that to the left of the current position is

  - `\bauthor={` Match `author={` preceded by a word boundary
  - `[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*` Match optional chars other than `{` `}` or match `{...}`
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `[A-Z]` Match an uppercase char A-Z
- `[^\s,]*,` Optionally match non whitespace chars except `,` and then match `,`
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\s+[A-Z][^\s,]*` Match 1+ whitespace chars, uppercase char A-Z, optional non whitespace chars except `,`
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat it 1 or more times
- `\b` a word boundary

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/DnaZyN/1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the problem one of the names that needs to be matched is  `Simader, G{"u}nter`. Your regex does not accept `{}` present in a word. How to handle that case too? (I have updated the question with this test case)

Comment: @ArpitShukla The second pattern does match that right? `(?<=\bauthor={[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*)[A-Z][^\s,]*,(?:\s+[A-Z][^\s,]*)+` https://regex101.com/r/gIRzWT/1

Comment: Yeah but that matches the ending `}` too which is not desired.

Comment: @ArpitShukla But that you can fix with `(?<=\bauthor={[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*)[A-Z][^\s,]*,(?:\s+[A-Z][^\s,]*\b)+` https://regex101.com/r/gtwMrK/1